# Loop over all 'test' with R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I made a new dataset which only have the variables:

I have then added a new variable to my data set, called Item:

`d <- test[, . (ID,  age,  test= test)]`

My question is now, that I want to make a function that will make a loop over all questions i have ?
is that possible?

Comment: do you have a sample of the `lmh14` so we can see what the data looked like before?

Comment: I have made an example in the question :)

Comment: What do you want to do in this loop? Most functions in R are vectorized so you usually don't need to write a look yourself. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: And how would you like question number displayed in the output table?

Comment: No i should not display in the output :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample set with only 2 questions. You can modify this to extend to 85.

In this case, I am using the `melt( )` function in the `data.table` package to convert the data from wide format to long format. The `id.vars` are variables you would like to keep as columns and the `measure.vars` are variables you would like condensed into a new column `Question` with corresponding values in `Response`.

```
library(data.table)

lmh14 <- data.table(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4),
  education_code = c(20,50,20,60),
  age = c(87,67,56,52),
  sex = c("F","M","M","M"),
  question1 = c(NA_real_,1,5,3),
  question2 = c(4,3,5,NA_real_))

lmh14_v2 <- melt(
  data = lmh14,
  id.vars = c("ID","education_code","sex"),
  measure.vars = c("question1","question2"),
  variable.name = "Question",
  value.name = "Response")

lmh14_v2
   ID education_code sex  Question Response
1:  1             20   F question1       NA
2:  2             50   M question1        1
3:  3             20   M question1        5
4:  4             60   M question1        3
5:  1             20   F question2        4
6:  2             50   M question2        3
7:  3             20   M question2        5
8:  4             60   M question2       NA
```

Comment: But that is not what I want - I want  the same data set as showed - item is only based on question1 but I need to make a for loop or a function over all 'item' (all questions) ? :)

Comment: @Hellihansen so you want one data table for each question?

Comment: yes but i dont want to manually do the lines 87 times - but a function that does it for me :)

Comment: @Hellihansen see other answer post

Answer (score 0):

Although the `assign` function is not the best, here is a loop that can do this for you.

```
for (Question in 1:2) {
  assign(
    x = paste0("Question",Question),
    value = lmh14[,.(ID, education_code, age, sex, item = get(paste0("question",Question)))])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! not to be difficult - what can I do if i have some values called "Question1", "question1_1" and "question1_text" - can this be included in the loop?